# Unity. How to pause script execution until animation ends?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to make the animation play and then the object changed coordinates, now the opposite is happening ?

```
     _animator.Play("Animation");
      WaitForAnimation(_animator);
    transform.position = StartPoint;
    dest = transform.position;
    Vector2 dir = Vector2.zero;
    _animator.SetFloat("DirX", 1);
    _animator.SetFloat("DirY", 0);


private IEnumerator WaitForAnimation(Animator animation)
{
    do
    {
        yield return null;
    } while (animation.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Animation"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call a `WaitForSeconds` function (or freeze the time, which is what you do) inside the IEnumerator funciton, time will only freeze inside itself. [More info here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

You should do something like:

```
    private IEnumerator WaitForAnimation(Animator animation) 
    {
         while (animation.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Animation"))
        {
           yield return null;
        }


         transform.position = StartPoint;
         dest = transform.position;
         Vector2 dir = Vector2.zero;
        _animator.SetFloat("DirX", 1);
        _animator.SetFloat("DirY", 0);
    }
```

Just a side note if the `while (animation.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Animation"))` doesn't work. I suggest calling a `WaitForSecondsRealTime(time)`. You could hardcode the time or [look at this.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-find-animation-clip-length.465751/)